# How to send stripe request to python backend as production(live) mode with react?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement subscription system with stripe.
The backend python code(flask) if below.
But "payment" method is always test mode and then I cannot use this script in production environment.

```py
@app.route('/sub', methods=['POST'])
def sub():
    email = request.json.get('email', None)
    payment_method = request.json.get('payment_method', None)
```

How can I send the request to this backend as production mode?
Does anyone show sample of react frontend scripts that can send requests as production mode???

Answer (score 1):

To make Stripe requests in live mode (not test mode), you need to use your live mode API keys located here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys. You are probably using your test mode API keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/apikeys.